# PowerShell fill up form and submit

Tags: powershell

I need to fill up a form of an internal site. I was able to successfully login to the portal page using this code

```bsh
$ie = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("https://some-internal-ip/login") 
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {Start-Sleep -m 100};

#Login 
$form = $ie.document.forms[0]
$inputs = $form.GetElementsByTagName("input")
($inputs | where {$_.Name -eq "username"}).Value = $username
($inputs | where {$_.Name -eq "password"}).Value = $password
($inputs | where {$_.Name -eq "action:Login"}).Click()

#after login - navigate to this link
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -m 100}
Start-Sleep -m 2000
$ie.Navigate("https://some-internal-ip/monitor/users")
```

Above works fine. It'll direct me to the new link where I need to fill another form. So I'm reusing my code above to fill up a form for a **user field** and **submit button**.

There are multiple forms inside this page so I want to narrow it down to this specific `id="trackingSearchForm"`.

HTML form:

```html
<form action="https://.../" method="POST" name="trackingSearchForm" id="trackingSearchForm" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="return false;">
<input name="user" onkeypress="keyPressHandler(this.form, event)" class="" type="text" id="user" value=">
<input type="button" class="submit" id="submitButton" value="Search" onclick="performSearch();">
```

Get ID of form and fill up

```bsh
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -m 100}
$form =  $ie.Document.Forms[0]
$form = ($ie.Document.Forms[0] | where {$_.Id -eq "trackingSearchForm"})
$inputs = $form.GetElementsByTagName("input")
($inputs | where {$_.name -eq "user"}).Value = "john"
($inputs | where {$_.Id -eq "submitButton"}).Click()
```

but I'm getting these errors:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
+ $inputs = $form.GetElementsByTagName("input")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
exists and can be set.
+ ($inputs | where {$_.Name -eq "user"}).Value = "john"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

The same code I used for the login form doesn't work on another form.

Comment: The meaning of the error is, that `$form` is empty.

Comment: Make `$ie.visible=$false` and perform actions step by step to see what's going on.

Comment: `$ie.Document.Forms[0]` is the first `<form>` element in the document. If that element doesn't have the ID "trackingSearchForm" `$form` will be empty, thus causing the error you observed. If you want an element with a specific ID why not use `$ie.Document.GetElementById("trackingSearchForm")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably in this line:

```
$form = ($ie.document.forms[0] | where {$_.id -eq "trackingSearchForm"})
```

Remove the index of `$forms`:

```
$form = ($ie.document.forms | where {$_.id -eq "trackingSearchForm"})
```

Comment: I feel so dumb for missing this out! thanks! follow-up question. if i have several forms in the same page do i just run through the index number e.g `forms[1]` to specify the form i want to fill-up?

Comment: Don't feel dumb, this is what happens when you're staring at a script for too long ;-)  When possible, I would always reference the forms by their id (like you did in your code).  Using a numerical index is possible, but is more likely to cripple your code when the HTML source changes in the future.

Comment: PS: maybe you could cycle through all forms, store them in a hash table, and reference them later on by their id (rather than index) in this (untested) way: `$forms = @{}; 
$ie.document.forms | % {
    $forms[$_.id] = $_
}` --> this should allow you to use `$forms["trackingSearchForm"]` in your script