# How can I make a working power shell script to fill forms on web pages?

Tags: forms, powershell, autocomplete, element

I m trying to get this powershell code i found, to log into my router login page but powershell give me a an error saying

- $Form | Get-Member
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand

Here is the code

```
    # Discover all page/form and elements to work with

    $url = 'http://192.168.8.1/#/login'
    ($FormElements = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable fe) 
    ($Form = $FormElements.Forms[0]) | Format-List -Force
    $Form | Get-Member 
    $Form.Fields

    # Interact with the site page

    $password = 'Mypassword'
    $loginUrl = 'http://192.168.8.1/#/login'

    $ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
    $ie.visible = $true
    $ie.navigate($loginUrl)

    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }

    ($ie.document.getElementById('gl-input loginInput') | 
    select -first 1).value = $password
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 

    $ie.Document.getElementsByName('new-password').Item().Click();
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. Use Windows PowerShell, no PowerShell (v7.0.x) or PowerShell Core (v6.x.x).
2. Initialize Internet Explorer before you will use this script.
3. Write your own script. This script is ... It has a lot of useless code like `$Form | Get-Member`. Have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57668335/powershell-fill-up-form-and-submit).